# how to hide cmd window when executing cmd with Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, cmd

I would like to execute multiple commands in a cmd shell from java:
sample:

```java
String cmdShell = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /K ";
String endCommand = cmdShell + "\"" + multiplecommands + " && exit" + "\"";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(endCommand);
final BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    LOGGER.debug("" + line);
}
proc.waitFor();
```

This opens the black window and closes after finished. Is there a way to hide this window. Or any other way to execute multiple commands without showing the cmd window ?

Comment: Some examples are listed [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/). Please give a try some of them may work as you want to.

Comment: Are you using `BufferReader` and `StreamReader` for executing the process? Or some other way?

Comment: I am using BufferedReader. I have updated the sample code.

Comment: Try creating your process using the following command: `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuildr processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", yourCommand); Process proc = processBuilder.start();`. Because you're using `start cmd.exe` would open a shell window

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code , in my case this code give all Directory of `C:\xampp` folder in my console ...without open CMD

```java
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd C:\\xampp && C: && dir");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

for more study you can read this [page](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-run-external-programs-by-using-java-processbuilder-class/189)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it useful "start" with "/min":

```
start /min .....
..........
exit
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start